# Regex for split or findall each digit python

Tags: python, regex

What is the best solution to split this `str` var into a continuous number list

My solution :

```
>>> str
> '2223334441214844'
>>> filter(None, re.split("(0+)|(1+)|(2+)|(3+)|(4+)|(5+)|(6+)|(7+)|(8+)|(9+)", str))
> ['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: Is a no cute or not optimised solution no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more flexible way would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which is made to match consecutive groups in iterables:

```
>>> s = '2223334441214844'
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(s)]
['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

The `key` would be the single key that is being grouped on (in your case, the digit). And the `group` is an iterable of all the items in the group. Since the source iterable is a string, each item is a character, so in order to get back the fully combined group, we need to join the characters back together.

You could also repeat the key for the length of the group to get this output:

```
>>> [key * len(list(group)) for key, group in itertools.groupby(s)]
['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

If you wanted to use regular expressions, you could make use of backreferences to find consecutive characters without having to specify them explicitly:

```
>>> re.findall('((.)\\2*)',  s)
[('222', '2'), ('333', '3'), ('444', '4'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('1', '1'), ('4', '4'), ('8', '8'), ('44', '4')]
```

For finding consecutive characters in a string, this is essentially the same that `groupby` will do. You can then filter out the combined match to get the desired result:

```
>>> [x for x, *_ in re.findall('((.)\\2*)',  s)]
['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution without regex (that is not specific to digits) would be to use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = '2223334441214844'
>>> [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to extract consecutive identical digits, you may use a matching approach using `r'(\d)\1*'` regex:

```
import re
s='2223334441214844'
print([x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(\d)\1*', s)])
# => ['222', '333', '444', '1', '2', '1', '4', '8', '44']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8eb7hG)

Here,

- `(\d)` - matches and captures into Group 1 any digit
- `\1*` - a backreference to Group 1 matching the same value, 0+ repetitions.

This solution can be customized to match any specific consecutive chars (instead of `\d`, you may use `\S` - non-whitespace, `\w` - word, `[a-fA-F]` - a specific set, etc.). If you replace `\d` with `.` and use `re.DOTALL` modifier, it will work as the `itertools` solutions posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group and backreference.

```
str = '2223334441214844'

import re
print([i[0] for i in re.findall(r'((\d)\2*)', str)])
```

`\2` matches whatever the `(\d)` capture group matched. The list comprehension is needed because when the RE contains capture groups, `findall` returns a list of the capture groups, not the whole match. So we need an extra group to get the whole match, and then need to extract that group from the result.

Answer (score 0):

> **What about without importing any external module ?**

You can create your own logic in pure python without importing any module Here is recursive approach,

```
string_1='2223334441214844'

list_2=[i for i in string_1]


def con(list_1):
    group = []
    if not list_1:
        return 0
    else:
        track=list_1[0]
        for j,i in enumerate(list_1):
            if i==track[0]:
                group.append(i)
            else:
                print(group)
                return con(list_1[j:])

        return group



print(con(list_2))
```

output:

```
['2', '2', '2']
['3', '3', '3']
['4', '4', '4']
['1']
['2']
['1']
['4']
['8']
['4', '4']
```